# Why there is 'no size available' on my subscription tho I am given 150$ credits per month?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am a beta Microsoft Learn Student Ambassador and I'm exploring the azure which is provided for free every month to a MLSA. However I am not able to create virtual machine due to the unavailability of size.

Answer (score 1):

It is a soft limitation Microsoft has set to new subscriptions:

> We’re implementing a few temporary restrictions designed to balance the best possible experience for all of our customers. We have placed limits on free offers to prioritize capacity for existing customers. We also have limits on certain resources for new subscriptions. These are ‘soft’ quota limits, and customers can raise support requests to increase these limits.

([source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/))

You can try filing a support request to get access to VMs. You might be able to do that using the steps listened [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/per-vm-quota-requests)